# How to solve this partial derivatives having summation?

Tags: derivatives, summation

I was reading a research paper, and I got stuck at this partial differentiation.

[This is given in that research paper....Please click it to get the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUiLo.png)

Now, I got stuck at Equation (13),, how partial derivative was done, where does summation gone.

Please provide me solution.

EDITED: [I solve this in this way. Please click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Tpk.jpg)

Please tell me if it is correct or not. Image is in the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you have

$$F(x_1,...,x_n)= f_1(x_1)+...+f_n(x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x_i)$$

Then

$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x_i}}=\frac{\partial{f_1}}{\partial{x_i}} +...+\frac{\partial{f_n}}{\partial{x_i}} = \frac{\partial{f_i}}{\partial{x_i}}$$

All the terms which drop out do so because they are constant with respect to $x_i$.

In this case, the author is using $P_i$ instead of $x_i$

Comment: Please check my solution, Its in edited part.

Comment: If you followed the rules of calculus, you should be fine. If my answer  helped answer your original question, you can upvote and/or accept it.